# is Couchbase Lite update views(indexes) automatically when we insert new docs ? or we need to do it manually?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view, couchbase-sync-gateway

i started researching on mobile embed databases and i came across couchbase , awesome.still i didn't understand some of the concepts , one of them is how to work with views and queries. they are saying that views are indexes. but they never documented that it updates on new inserts and all sort of things , so i am sort of confused. so if possible , please let me know the overall logic and understanding behind Views and queries in couchbase lite. and how many ways we can use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, views are indexes and they are updated according to the settings on a query when it is run (more specifically [this one](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html#indexupdatemode-indexupdatemode--get-set-).  The naming is not consistent between platforms right now, but you have three choices.  The default is to update the view before the query is run.  The other choices are to update it after the query is run, or not update it at all.